# How to use the bigquery service object

Tags: python, google-api, google-bigquery, google-cloud-platform, google-apis-explorer

I'm trying to learn how to call the BigQuery API from Python using a service account. I'm following the [docs here](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/start/get_started#collections). This URL actually has the bookmark close to the bit I'm stuck on. I've got to this line:

```
bigquery = build('bigquery', 'v2', http=http_auth)
```

And the lack of error message and list of attributes seems to indicate that it has worked, but I'm stuck on what to do with it. I've read what I'm supposed to do with it, but my attempt is wrong and I can't find the relevant documentation to unblock myself. Or I've found the right doc, but don't understand what to do with it.

From scanning GQB documentation this is what I've tried:

```
sql ="""
#standardSQL
SELECT corpus AS title, COUNT(*) AS unique_words
FROM `publicdata.samples.shakespeare`
GROUP BY title
ORDER BY unique_words DESC
LIMIT 10
"""

collection = bigquery.jobs()
request = collection.query(
    kind="bigquery#queryRequest",
    query=sql,
    useQueryCache=True,
    useLegacySql=False
)

response = request.execute()
```

This I came up with from the [GBQ API documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/jobs/query) and the documentation listed above.

Which gives:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/.../gbq.py", line 37, in <module>
    useLegacySql=False
  File "/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/googleapiclient/discovery.py", line 717, in method
    raise TypeError('Got an unexpected keyword argument "%s"' % name)
TypeError: Got an unexpected keyword argument "kind"
```

OK, so it's clearly wrong. I suspect that if I were more experienced at consuming APIs this would be obvious, but I can't seem to bring this home. Please can someone point me in the right direction, is there a guide to this that I've missed?

Comment: But that error shows you are doing `collection.query(....sql=sql...)`, not `query=sql` as shown in your code.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out @DanielRoseman - I've tried a couple of things out. I'll edit to make it consistent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend you to use the official [Python API Client](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-python) for BigQuery as it already handles all these connections and setups automatically for you.

Running a query ends up being pretty simple. Example:

```
import uuid
import os
os.environ['GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS'] = 'path/to/your/jsonscrets.json'

from google.cloud.bigquery import Client
bqc = Client()

sql ="""
#standardSQL
SELECT corpus AS title, COUNT(*) AS unique_words
FROM `publicdata.samples.shakespeare`
GROUP BY title
ORDER BY unique_words DESC
LIMIT 10
"""

job = bqc.run_async_query(str(uuid.uuid4()), sql)
job.use_legacy_sql = False
job.begin()

job_result = job.result()
data = list(job_result.fetch_data())
```

Comment: Brilliant - just what I was looking for and much simpler. Many thanks!